# What aspect of the github API are the PyRESTo docs referring to for its tag model?

Tags: github-api

At the very end of [the relations section](http://pyresto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#relations) in the PyResto docs, we see a model for a tag in [the github API](http://developer.github.com):

```
class Tag(GitHubModel):
    _path = '/repos/{user}/{repo}/tags/{name}'
    _pk = ('user', 'repo', 'name')
    commit = Foreign(Commit, embedded=True)
```

However, I cannot find any such REST path in the Github API:

- [this one](http://developer.github.com/v3/git/tags/) has `git` in the path and that is not part of the path in that `Tag` class. Furthermore, it is doubtful that `sha` in the documented github api path is the name as `name` in the class above.
- [this one](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-tags) does not have `/:name` appended to it.

Answer (score 0):

That part of their documentation was written over a year ago. I can attest (personally as the author of github3.py) that the API has changed quite a bit since then. I don't recall this endpoint ever existing, but if it did it's since been long removed. Also, it may never have existed and the authors of the documentation may have remembered it being in version 2 of the API (which was still supported around that time last year I think).